# ¿Como puedo abrir un modulo o aplicación con un botón en android?

Tags: java, android-studio

Quisiera abrir un ***módulo*** desde un botón en Android Studio, es como otro proyecto dentro del mismo, donde puedes tener otro *MainActivity*, otro layout, los que saben de Android Studio lo entenderán supongo.

Para hacerlo intente usando intents:

```
Intent open7 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.smeter");
    startActivity(open7);
```

Cuando creamos un ***módulo*** nos aparecen las mismas ventanas como si fuera a crear un proyecto nuevo, y podemos agregar otro nombre de *package*, usé el intent para abrir apps por *package* y no funcionó.

También utilicé el intent para abrir *activity.class* y así abrir el layout del módulo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
```

***Y no funcionó.***

Answer (score 4):

No te funciono porque únicamente estas realizando un `Intent` para abrir `MainActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
```

**La forma correcta de abrir un módulo o aplicación mediante su `packagename` es mediante un Intent pero se realiza de esta forma:**

```
 Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.smeter");
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            

 startActivity(intent);
```

si lo deseas realizar al dar click desde un botón, este es un ejemplo:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.smeter");
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);                 
         startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });
```

Comment: Lo había resuelto con ese intent ya, gracias!

Comment: Cuando se agrega un voto -1 es de ayuda explicar porque razón del mismo, para mejorar la respuesta o saber de algún tipo de error.