# Abrir Apk con otra Apk

Tags: java, android, apk

Estoy trabajando con Aplicaciones Android/ios. Me gustaría saber si es posible ejecutar una aplicación B usando una Aplicación A, con un botón

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Las aplicaciones están en el mismo dispositivo o en distintos dispositivos?¿Es relevante que estés trabajando con aplicaciones ios?

Comment: Esto ya fue preguntado : [¿Como puedo abrir un modulo o aplicación con un botón en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102612/como-puedo-abrir-un-modulo-con-un-boton-en-android-studio/104385#104385)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible. Debes conocer el nombre del otro paquete y lanzar un *intent* para poder lanzarlo, por ejemplo, con el siguiente código, puedes lanzar el *messenger* de Facebook:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.orca");
//si el paquete no está instalado, launchIntent será null
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Comment: Gracias!, eso es lo que estaba buscando

Comment: Enhorabuena. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues eso ayudará a futuros navegantes a identificarla como la respuesta que te ayudó a resolver tu duda/problema. Un saludo.